# Video player for playing .mpd files

Tags: ios, media-player, mpd

I want to play .mpd files in iPhone app and for that I tried VLC player but it's not working as per expectation and taking too much time to play the video. Is there any other option which i can use to play .mpd files like exoplayer in Android.

I have already implemented VLC media player for this purpose but now I'm looking for another option. Please help if any body have any idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

Google has released a player that can be used with or without their widevine DRM.

https://github.com/google/universal-dash-transmuxer